# How can we compare the time complexity of O(2^n) and Θ(2^n)?

Tags: algorithm, comparison, big-o, complexity-theory

I have to compare the time complexity of O(2^n) and Θ(2^n) for a homework problem .

I believe that Θ(2^n) is better since it covers the upper and the lower bound of 2^n but I'm not sure.Thank you for your time .

Comment: `O(2^n)` means *at most*, *not more than*, when `Θ(2^n)` means *exactly*. So usually `O(2^n)` is better (say, `O(2^n)` can be `O(n)` in a typical case) for the input which *large enough*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, if you have `O(2^n)` would be better. Because you can have hope that just in the worst case scenario it would be bad. But that worst case might happen rarely. Hence, the average time complexity could be much better. For example, you have a situation that takes happen with the probability of `1/2^n` and the algorithm runs for this case with `2^n` computation cost, but the cost of the algorithm for all other cases is `1`. Hence, the complexity of this algorithm is `O(2^n)`, but the average complexity is `O(1)`.

However likes the above example, cannot happen for an algorithm with `\Theta(2^n)`.
But in `Theta(2^n)` you will be sure the average time complexity is `2^n` and it could be awful.

Comment: Big-O and Theta does not relate to best, worst and average case in the way you describe. Some given big-O or Theta representation would refer to one specific case (e.g. "The average case time complexity is O(2^n)"), not all 3 cases at once. See: [How do O and Ω relate to worst and best case?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/how-do-o-and-%CE%A9-relate-to-worst-and-best-case).

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks. I knew. And I didn't say it is! I said, "you can have hope"! and "might be".

Comment: I, possibly incorrectly, assumed by "worst case" you mean the worst-case time complexity. If that's not what you meant, and you mean the worst-case *scenario* in another sense, can you clarify that part a bit?

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, it is a little bit confusing. Sure. It is updated.

Comment: Your update matches what I initially thought you meant. The algorithm you describe will be Theta(2^n) in the worst case and Theta(1) in the average case. "The time complexity of [an] algorithm" would only have a clear definition if it takes the same amount of time in *every* case. Although informally it usually refers to either the average or worst case. The mathematics of calculating time complexity requires each input size to only have one time value.

Comment: What is `Theta(2^n)` in the worst case?! it is not a clear meaning. Notice that, it is just an example of an algorithm for `O(2^n)`.

Comment: "The algorithm you describe will be Theta(2^n) in the worst case" means "The algorithm you describe will have a worst-case time complexity of Theta(2^n)". I'd suggest reading the link I posted above. I don't think I can explain it much better than that.